# Display BMP using CreateWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I want to display a logo at the top of the screen.  The logo is a bmp file.  I made an example program to show what happens in full working code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

char szClassName[] = "BmpTestApp";

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;

    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wincl.hIcon = NULL;
    wincl.hIconSm = NULL;
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;

    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
        return 0;

    DEVMODE display;
    EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &display);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_OVERLAPPED, szClassName, "Bitmap Display Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 500, 500, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    while(GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    return messages.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        HWND logo;
        case WM_CREATE:
            RECT hwndRect;
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, &hwndRect);
            int winWidth;
            int winHeight;
            winWidth = hwndRect.right - hwndRect.left;
            winHeight = hwndRect.bottom - hwndRect.top;

            HBITMAP logoImage;
            logoImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_LOGO), IMAGE_BITMAP, winWidth - 180, winHeight - 530, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
            logo = CreateWindow(WC_STATIC, NULL, SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, winWidth - 180, winHeight - 530, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            SendMessage(logo, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)logoImage);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}


// resource.rc
IDB_LOGO BITMAP "Logo.bmp"

// resource.h
#define IDB_LOGO 300
```

When I run my program, there is just a box the size of the image, but no image inside.  Logo.bmp is definately in the folder where my resource.rc file is and all the other project files.  Why is it not displaying?  Thanks.

Comment: -1 the code (as i'm writing this) is not the real code.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling DefWindowProc for the messages that you don't handle.

Comment: The code I posted was just the part of my code that was displaying the logo.  I am calling DefWindowProc at `default:`.

Comment: could you show us a complete program? Also supply details of how it fails and error codes.

Comment: I just editted it into my question now.  There isn't an error code, it just doesn't display the image.

Comment: how do you know there are on errors? You don't check return codes?

Answer (score 2):

Drop the SS_CENTER style flag, it conflicts with SS_BITMAP.

Comment: Same result, but thanks anyway, it might have been a later problem.

Comment: SS_CENTER | SS_BITMAP == 0x0001 | 0x000e == 0x000f.  Which is SS_ENHMETAFILE.  That's quite wrong.  Maybe there are other problems, you don't check for any errors so anything is possible.  Thanks anyway.